# All my Developer and Distribution certificates are showing as not trusted

Tags: ios, certificate

All my Developer and distribution certificates are showing as 'certificate not trusted'. Till yesterday all are working fine.

[image]

[image]

Please help me out. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Open the certificate and check the Trust section and set it to Always Trust and see if it works.

Comment: Tried that not working

Comment: @Balu have you update anything in mac ?

Comment: @NiravKotecha No i just installed latest Xcode 10.1

Comment: @Balu in keychain-->certificates, your "Apple Worldwide Developer Relations Certification Authority" is valid or not ?

Comment: @NiravKotecha Ya its valid only

Comment: @NiravKotecha  Thanks. After I installed latest Xcode restarted my MacBook its working fine.

Comment: @MohammadRF thanks for the quick response.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just download the certificate from [WWDRCAG3](https://www.apple.com/certificateauthority/AppleWWDRCAG3.cer) and install it. If the it doesn't works have a look on https://developer.apple.com/de/support/expiration/. you can get the intermediate certificate link.

Comment: This file solved our issue of "iPhone Distribution : certificate is not trusted", after installing AppleWWDRCAG3.cer, our distribution certificate is valid.